# How do we deal with such arrangement problems?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

> 15 different balls are kept in a straight line.
>
> Then their order is changed such that no ball is adjacent to a ball which it was adjacent to earlier. In how many ways can this task be achieved?

I thought of the negation approach, which would lead us to $15!-(\text{no of ways in which at least 1 ball is adjacent to one of its previous partners})$

But that's not too useful either, as the number of cases (and subcases) is still far too high..

$\textbf{Source:}$ My friend gave this problem to me as a challenge about 2 weeks ago.

Comment: @almagest Well..there are no answers there..

Comment: I think it is answered in this duplicate http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/439559/permutations-with-no-two-adjacent-numbers-being-equal